# Display many, many, MANY decimal places in python

Tags: python, decimal

I am approximating phi to 50 decimal places and want to return the value I have computed. I do not want to print it otherwise I can't use it in calculations.
How can I do this because python only wants to display 11 decimal places or something like that?
Thanks

Comment: Google your question's title and you will find a bunch of useful results and potential solutions.

Answer (score 0):

python floats do not have that precision. you need to use python decimal:

```
from decimal import getcontext, Decimal
getcontext().prec = 50
print(Decimal(1) / Decimal(7))
```

the drawback is that calculations with these will take much more time than the ones with float.